# Handling parsed text

Tags: r, parsing, web-scraping, imdb

I would like to count the amount of number smaller than x in a parsed text.

This is the code that gives me the list:

```
library(rvest)
library(reshape2)


td <- read_html(x = "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1287124/?ref_=tt_ov_dr") 
list<- as.list(td %>% # feed `main.page` to the next step%>% # load the page
    html_nodes(".filmo-row") %>% # isloate the text
    html_text())
```

Does anybody know how to count, for instance, the amount numbers smaller than 2017?

(to be complete; end goal is to count the amount of director credits before a certain year)

Comment: Please indicate all packages you are using.

Comment: rvest and reshape2

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have:

```
text <- "asdasd8927askdmasjdo89jans1982736djnaos987anksdjnj2008da"
```

Assuming numbers are always enclosed by anything but `[0-9]`, then you could write a function which will do this:

```
idx <- gregexpr("[0-9]+", text)[[1]]
lens <- attr(idx, "match.length")
nums <- lapply(seq_along(idx), function(i) {
  substr(text, idx[i], idx[i] + lens[i] - 1)
})
nums <- as.numeric(nums)
```

(`?grep` and `?substr` for explanation)
Finally you can count the numbers which are greater than 2017.

```
sum(nums > 2017)
```

**Edit** (Comment)

Let's say we only want to look at exactly 4 digit numbers, then the regex (and the `substr` indices) can be adjusted. Now we search "Not a Number" 4 times "a Number" "Not a Number". So, to extract only the "number" part we start `substr` one position later and stop one position earlier.

```
idx <- gregexpr("[^0-9][0-9]{4}[^0-9]", text)[[1]]
lens <- attr(idx, "match.length")
nums <- lapply(seq_along(idx), function(i) {
  substr(text, idx[i] + 1, idx[i] + lens[i] - 2)
})
nums <- as.numeric(nums)
```

Now `nums` contains only the 2 4-digit numbers.

```
nums
sum(nums > 2017)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this does not work for my data. (just to be complete; I want to count the director credits before a certain year, see: http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1287124/?ref_=tt_ov_dr)

Comment: Well you could adjust the code to your specific string. If you only want to look at numbers that are 4 digits long, you can use this regex: `[^0-9][0-9]{4}[^0-9]`. Then the regex searches for a pattern "NaN 4 times a number NaN". So, you have to adjust the start and stop indices in the `substr` function +1 and -1: `substr(text, idx[i] + 1, idx[i] + lens[i] - 2)`